# Is it possible to remove shadow on a specific image via css

Tags: css

It is possible to remove a shadow on a specific image that appears on many pages many time on a site.

This is the image that should not have a shadow.

http://www.101calendartemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/print.png

The image appears on this site on pages such as this one:

http://www.101calendartemplates.com/august-calendar-2/

This is the code that was used to add a shadow to all other images on the site:

```html
.alignnone {
    border: #b9b9b9 solid 1px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
```

Comment: Remove the `alignnone` class that is adding the shadow on those elements.

Comment: if u don wants the shadow then remove the alignnone class to the particular image which dont want

Comment: Is there a way to do it without changing the class since the image appears hundreds of time on different pages? Could you give an image a class via css instead of editing each image?

Comment: Why does [this blue calendar thing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iSRzH.png) not have a shadow? I don’t think this is intended. There’s little semantic information in the markup to distinguish the two types of images. You could try to add `.entry-content a:not([target]) img{box-shadow: none;}` to the CSS.

Comment: Xufox, you are right. I didn't notice that before. I added the code but it still doesn't have a shadow.

Answer (score 1):

You can target the img by src attribute:

```
img[src$="print.png"] { 
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow:    none;
  box-shadow:         none;
}
```

The "$=" matches on any value that ends in the specified value.